# Sub component template not rendered

Tags: angular, jhipster

I created a brand new project with jhipster using angular, internationalization and maven. 
The project compiles and runs without any problem. 
Than I created a new angular component with:

`ng generate component my-new-component`

I included that component into src/main/webapp/app/layouts/main/main.component.html

```
<jhi-page-ribbon></jhi-page-ribbon>
<div>
<router-outlet name="navbar"></router-outlet>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="card jh-card">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet>
</div>
<jhi-footer></jhi-footer>
<jhi-my-new-component></jhi-my-new-component>
</div>
```

and also into src/main/webapp/app/home/home.component.html

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
    <span class="hipster img-fluid rounded"></span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-9">

         <h1 class="display-4" jhiTranslate="home.title">Welcome, Java Hipster!    </h1>
      <jhi-my-new-component></jhi-my-new-component>
    <p class="lead" jhiTranslate="home.subtitle">This is your homepage</p>
```

The component into main.component.html is correctly rendered.
But on the second case, home.component.html, the component tag is rendered, but component's template is not rendered.

Any suggestion will be really appreciated.

Some info:

> Using JHipster version installed locally in current project's node_modules
>   4.14.1
>
> our global Angular CLI version (1.7.3) is greater than your local
>   version (1.6.6). The local Angular CLI version is used.

Comment: what do you meen that  the component tag is rendered, but component's template is not rendered ?

Comment: That on the first case I have: <jhi-my-new-component><p> my-new-component works! </p> </jhi-my-new-component>, 
but on the second I have
<jhi-my-new-component _ngcontent-c1=""></jhi-my-new-component>

Comment: Do you have several modules or just one only ?

Comment: Are both components (main and home) belongs to one module or different?

Comment: They belongs to different modules, main and new-component  belongs to the top level app.module.ts while home has its own home.module.ts.

Comment: Just an update, I moved the component in a shared modules that declare and export it. In this way it works.

Comment: This probably means that you did not import the new module in home