# angular-tree-component not working in component

Tags: angular, tree, jhipster

I had been use jhipster gen a web application,need display a tree in component,
according doc of https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs
in     main.component.html, and main.component.ts add it display OK,
but in home.component.html and home.component.ts add same code, it render empty node.

Comment: pls add relevant code

Comment: like post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49318772/sub-component-template-not-rendered, except the component is different,I use tree component, he use jhi-my-new-component.

Comment: Do you have any errors? Can you please add some screenshot

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in your readme to import the library?

Comment: follow is my step: 0.in package.json add "angular-tree-component": "^7.2.1", 1. in app.modules.ts  file add import { TreeModule} from 'angular-tree-component'; @NgModule({ imports: [TreeModule,....] 2.in vender.scss add @import '~angular-tree-component/dist/angular-tree-component.css';

Comment: 3.in main.component.ts add nodes and options static data,in main.component.html add tree-root display OK，4.in home.component.ts and home.component.html do same thing,but display empty.

Comment: https://www.higowealth.com/resources/images/error.png

Answer (score 0):

in home.modules.ts add follow line
import { TreeModule} from 'angular-tree-component';
then import TreeModule,it is OK.